# Contains not working properly (Check if an element already exists in DataGrid)

Tags: c#, wpf

I want check if an element is already present in DataGrid, so I made this code:

```
if (MainWindow.AppWindow.Teams_DataGrid.Items.Contains(squadra))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Already present."); 
}
```

but the condition is ever false. I insert the values in the DataGrid in this way:

```
MainWindow.AppWindow.Teams_DataGrid.Items.Add(new
{
       code = rdr.GetStringOrNull(7),
       name = rdr.GetStringOrNull(6),
       championship = rdr.GetStringOrNull(4),
       shortName = rdr.GetStringOrNull(8),
       squadMarketValue = rdr.GetStringOrNull(9)
});
```

**NB:** rdr is a reader of a query. And code, name and other stuff is binding in the DataGrid Xaml like:

```
Binding="{Binding Path = 'name'}"
```

Why the condition is ever false? What I doing wrong?

COMPLETE CODE:

```
string stm = @" SELECT * 
                            FROM teams l 
                            LEFT JOIN soccerseason s ON s.id = l.id
                            WHERE caption LIKE " + "'" + MainWindow.AppWindow.League.SelectedValue.ToString() +
                            "%' AND s.years = " + MainWindow.AppWindow.Season.SelectedValue.ToString();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(stm, database.Connection);
            MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                string squadra = rdr.GetStringOrNull(6);

                if (MainWindow.AppWindow.Teams_DataGrid.Items.Contains(squadra))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Squadra già inserita."); 
                }
                else 
                {
                    MainWindow.AppWindow.Teams_DataGrid.Items.Add(new
                    {
                        code = rdr.GetStringOrNull(7),
                        name = rdr.GetStringOrNull(6),
                        championship = rdr.GetStringOrNull(4),
                        shortName = rdr.GetStringOrNull(8),
                        squadMarketValue = rdr.GetStringOrNull(9)
                    });
                }
            }
            rdr.Close();
```

Comment: you have to iterate through each rows and check whether it contains or not?

Comment: What is `squadra` here? You really haven't shown us enough code to help us help you.

Comment: Are the casings the same between the DataGrid.Items and the value of squadra?

Comment: Type you insert to datagrid is different than the type you try to read with :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Items` collection of your DataGrid does not contain strings, so `Contains` will always return false.

You will have to find the item where the `name` property is equal to the value of `squadra`. However, this can't be done with an anonymous item type, so the first thing to do is to create an item class, e.g. like this:

```
public class Team
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Championship { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string SquadMarketValue { get; set; }
}
```

Now you would add items like this:

```
using System.Linq;
...

var squadra = rdr.GetStringOrNull(6);

if (MainWindow.AppWindow.Teams_DataGrid.Items.Cast<Team>().Any(t => t.Name == squadra))
{
     MessageBox.Show("Squadra già inserita."); 
}
else 
{
     MainWindow.AppWindow.Teams_DataGrid.Items.Add(new Team
     {
         Code = rdr.GetStringOrNull(7),
         Name = squadra,
         Championship = rdr.GetStringOrNull(4),
         ShortName = rdr.GetStringOrNull(8),
         SquadMarketValue = rdr.GetStringOrNull(9)
     });
 }
```

---

That said, it would make sense to create a view model with a Teams collection property, e.g.

```
public ObservableCollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
```

and bind the DataGrid's `ItemsSource` property to the `Teams` view model property. Now you would find existing Team objects and add now ones in the `Teams` collection, without directly accessing the DataGrid.

Comment: Good solution but, I get this error when I add a second value: 
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type '<> f__AnonymousType1`5 [System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String]' on type 'Team'.
on this line: 
if (MainWindow.AppWindow.Teams_DataGrid.Items.Cast<Team>().Any(t => t.Name == squadra))

Comment: Because you forgot to replace `Items.Add(new { ... })` by `Items.Add(new Team { ... })`.